# plotting interaction from mixed model lme4 with CI bands

Tags: lme4, interaction, mixed-models

I have the following mixed effects model:

```
p1 <- lmer(log(price) ~ year*loca + (1|author), data = df)
```

'year' is continuous
'loca' is categorical variable with 2 levels

I am trying to plot the significant interaction from this model.

The following code (using the visreg package) plots the lines from each of the two 'loca' but it does not produce a 95% confidence band:

```
visreg(p1, "year", by = "loca", overlay = T,
   line=list(lty = 1, col = c("grey", "black")), points=list(cex=1, pch=19, 
   col = c("grey", "black")), type="conditional", axes = T)
```

Then, I tried the following code which allows me to plot the lines, but with no data points on top and no CIs:

```
visreg(p1, "year", by = "loca", overlay = T, 
   line=list(lty = 1, col = c("grey60", "black")), points=list(cex=1, 
   pch=19, col = c("grey", "black")),
   type="conditional", trans = exp, fill.par = list(col = c("grey80", 
   "grey70")))
```

I get CI bands when I use type = 'contrast' rather than 'conditional'. However, this doesn't work when I try to backtransform the price as above using trans = exp.

Overall I need to be able to plot the interaction with the following attributes:

- Confidence bands
- backtransformed points
- predicted line (one for each level of 'loca')

More than happy to try other methods....but I can't seem to find any that work so far.

Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

one possibility is with the use of the `effects` package:

```
library(effects)
eff.p1 <- effect("year*loca", p1, KR=T)
```

then you could either directly plot it with what the package provides and customize it from there:

```
plot(eff.p1)
```

or take what effect produces and plot it with ggplot in a nicer plot:

```
eff.p1 <- as.data.frame(eff.p1)
ggplot(eff.p1, aes(year, linetype=factor(loca),
                                     color = factor(loca))) +
  geom_line(aes(y = fit, group=factor(loca)), size=1.2) +
  geom_line(aes(y = lower,
                group=factor(loca)), linetype =3) +
  geom_line(aes(y = upper,
                group=factor(loca)), linetype =3) +
  xlab("year") +
  ylab("Marginal Effects on Log Price") +
  scale_colour_discrete("") +
  scale_linetype_discrete("") +
  labs(color='loca') + theme_minimal()
```

I can't really try the code without the data, but I think it should work.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
install.packages(sjPlot)
library(sjPlot)
plot_model(p1, type = "int", terms = c(year,loca), ci.lvl = 0.95)
```

Although it comes out with some warnings about labels, testing on my data, it does the back transformation automatically and seems to work fine. Customising should be easy, because I believe sjPlot uses ggplot.

EDIT: @Daniel points out that alternative options which allow more customization would be plot_model(type = "pred", ...) or plot_model(type = "eff", ...)

Comment: Yes, plots are based on ggplot. Alternative options which allow more customization would be `plot_model(type = "pred", ...)` or `plot_model(type = "eff", ...)`.

Comment: Thanks - I'll add that to the answer